Push DHCP DNS servers to clients
My openvpn server gets its DNS servers from DHCP, so in theory they could change any time.
Right now, I'm assuming they won't change, and I have hardcoded them into the openvpn config file:
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.2.3.4"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.2.3.5"

This works, but the problem with doing it this way should be obvious.
How do I get openvpn to automatically push whatever DNS servers the system currently has?

For a host offering services, the DNS configuration should not be changing frequently. Adding the capability to deal with such a scenario in your DHCP server would add a lot of complexity and dependencies. So there's not much motivation for someone else to solve your problem.
Assuming you mean "push whatever DNS servers the openvpn server host currently has?" a couple of really obvious solution would be:

regenerate and apply the openvpn config when the DNS servers are changed on your host

Specify the openvpn server host AS the DNS server and relay the traffic from there - dnsmasq makes this trivial to set up.


